# Apache Ignite service won't start if second node is running

Tags: microservices, ignite

I have a basic service that starts a Jetty server and responds to requests. The repo is here: https://github.com/danellis/ignite-test

When I run Ignite with that configuration file, and both my service's JAR and the Scala library JAR in libs, everything seems to work as expected. However, if I start a second, identical node on another computer, it delays a few seconds during startup, then starts without my service running (but without any exceptions). If I restart the original node while another node is running, the same problem then occurs there too.

Here's the `ignite -v` output.

Single node: 
https://gist.github.com/danellis/6678a28b38084598de84cd87ba7773af

Second node: 
https://gist.github.com/danellis/63605ba511801d6867439472befe22db

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set `<property name="totalCount" value="1"/>`, it make service runs as cluster singleton. try remove it.

Comment: Yesssss... you are a star. Thank you for spotting that!